# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException while building a simple android app using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded the Android Studio and trying to build a simple Login Activity. But the Make Project fails with this error.

```
Environment: Windows 7 64 bit
```

---

Gradle: 
trouble writing output: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-1 MessageDigest not available

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':MyApp:dexDebug'.

  > Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed. See output

  Try:

  `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`

---

I have made sure the Gradle zip was downloaded and installed properly

Any hints what else should I check for?

Answer (score 1):

I was using IBM JDK. Switching to Sun/Oracle JDK fixed the problem.

Comment: I also had this, yet the Oracle JRE was on my path.

Turns out I had also set JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME to the IBM ones